# Scope operator for base class in super multiple non-virtual inheritance

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

Consider this (completely non-nonsensical, but perfectly valid) class inheritance:

```
struct Area { int size; };
struct Pattern { int size; };

struct R : Area, Pattern {};
struct C : Area, Pattern {};

struct X: R , C {};
```

Let's see a graph of this *great* hierarchy:

```
Area  Pattern
  |\  /|   
  | \/ |
  | /\ |  
  |/  \|
  R    C
   \  /
    \/
    X
```

Now, if I am not mistaken, X should have 4 `size` members.

**How to refer to them using the scope operator?**

The obvious solution doesn't work:

```
X x;
x.R::Area::size = 24;
```

clang error:

> ```
> 23 : <source>:23:3: error: ambiguous conversion from derived class 'X' to base class 'Area':
>     struct X -> struct R -> struct Area
>     struct X -> struct C -> struct Area
>   x.R::Area::size = 8;
>   ^
> 1 error generated.
> ```

gcc error:

> ```
> <source>: In function 'auto test()':
> 23 : <source>:23:14: error: 'Area' is an ambiguous base of 'X'
>    x.R::Area::size = 8;
>               ^~~~
> ```

---

Some much needed clarification:

- I was just messing around, it is not a real design

  - so please don't point the problems with the design
  - and please don't think this is a good design. It is... not - to say the least
- This is strictly about the **C++ syntax** to resolve the ambiguity.

  - please don't suggest to not do it
  - please don't suggest virtual inheritance.

Comment: Why would you even think of such an atrocity? :)

Comment: @DanielTrugman I was experimenting with the scope operator. Nobody said experiments have to be pretty :)

Comment: Just make sure your experiment doesn't escape the confines of your laboratory. This is horror film material right there.

Comment: Your class hierarchy diagram does not match the class hierarchy. Shared parent implies virtual inheritance.

Comment: @user2079303 - It doesn't match the object layout. I think it's an acceptable summation of the class hierarchy itself, however.

Comment: And that distinction is important. Because `R::Area` names the type `Area`. There is no `Area` of `R`, only `Area`. Hence the ambiguity, despite the attempt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

something like `static_cast<R&>(x).Area::size = 8;`

which is as ugly as it should be :)

To clarify why the original code doesn't work, it's worth mentioning that a qualified id has the form (among others) `type-name::id` so `x.R::Area::y` is equivalent to `using T = R::Area; x.T::y;` that clearly does not help as far as disambiguation is concerned.

Comment: @bolov - No, it can't. `R::Area` is the same type as `Area`. The "path" you use to name it is immaterial. You need to disambiguate based on *object*

Comment: indeed, the grammar of x.A::B::C::y is parsed as x.(A::B::C)::y where A::B::C is the type name part of the qualified id expression ...

Comment: thank you, the explanation why R::Area doesn't work is what I was looking for.